# Is it possible to declare a tuple struct whose members are private, except for initialization?

Tags: initialization, rust, visibility, declaration

Is it possible to declare a tuple struct where the members are hidden for all intents and purposes, except for declaring?

```
// usize isn't public since I don't want users to manipulate it directly
struct MyStruct(usize); 

// But now I can't initialize the struct using an argument to it.
let my_var = MyStruct(0xff)
//                    ^^^^
//                    How to make this work?
```

Is there a way to keep the member private but still allow new structs to be initialized with an argument as shown above?

As an alternative, a method such as `MyStruct::new` can be implemented, but I'm still interested to know if its possible to avoid having to use a method on the type since it's shorter, and nice for types that wrap a single variable.

---

#### Background

Without going into too many details, the only purpose of this type is to wrap a single type *(a helper which hides some details, adds some functionality and is optimized away completely when compiled)*, in this context it's not exactly exposing hidden internals to use the `Struct(value)` style initializing.
Further, since the wrapper is zero overhead, its a little misleading to use the `new` method which is often associated with allocation/creation instead of casting.

Just as it's convenient type `(int)v` or `int(v)`, instead of `int::new(v)`,  I'd like to do this for my own type.

It's used often, so the ability to use short expression is very convenient. Currently I'm using a macro which calls a `new` method, its OK but a little awkward/indirect, hence this question.

Comment: I don't believe something like this exists in... any language? You want selective visibility without having any method that encapsulates the value? Short of a reflection feature that lets you forcefully set even hidden fields (like C#/.NET has, for example) I imagine you won't find much similar in many other languages? I'm honestly confused by the requirement: "I want this to not be accessed at all but actually I do want it to be accessible".

Comment: I was hoping there might be some way to override & implement what runs when calling `SomeStruct(some_value)` - so having the value kept as hidden wouldn't be prevented.

Comment: Well, in most languages you do this via a constructor overload which accepts a default parameter for an encapsulated field. I'd say that points you directly to the `new` approach.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead ocaml allow this kind of zero cost abstractions . They are called phantom types and they only exists at compile time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strictly speaking this isn't possible in Rust.

However the desired outcome can be achieved using a normal `struct` with a like-named function *(yes, this works!)*

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    value: usize,
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub fn MyStruct(value: usize) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct { value }
}
```

Now, you can write `MyStruct(5)` but not access the internals of `MyStruct`.

Comment: This works very well from what I can tell, interestingly function name shadowing doesn't seem to cause any problems with existing references to the type.

Comment: Many languages have different namespaces for types and values. Ocaml, the main inspiration for rust does, so I assume rust does too

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that such a concept is not possible, but for a good reason. Each member of a struct, unless marked with `pub`, is admitted as an implementation detail that should not raise to the surface of the public API, regardless of when and how the object is currently being used. Under this point of view, the question's goal reaches a conundrum: wishing to keep members private while letting the API user define them arbitrarily is not only uncommon but also not very sensible.

As you mentioned, having a method named `new` is the recommended approach of doing that. It's not like you're compromising code readability with the extra characters you have to type. Alternatively, for the case where the struct is known to wrap around an item, making the member public can be a possible solution. That, on the other hand, would allow any kind of mutations through a mutable borrow (thus possibly breaking the struct's invariants, as mentioned by @MatthieuM). This decision depends on the intended API.

Comment: This makes sense, though in my use case, its only a single variable and the struct only exists to wrap a single type, so allowing `Struct(value)` isn't exposing internals in the same way it would for many struct members. - added note to the original question

Comment: In that case you may consider making the member public (answer updated). Either way, I cannot think of a sufficient reason for a "shorter-hand" constructor to be integrated into the language at this point.

Comment: Another reason is invariants. `struct Even(i64)` guarantees that its inner member is always even, it people can initialize it to any value...